# Maximize the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the points $(x,y)$ and the directions for which the directional derivative of $f(x,y)=3x^2+y^2$ has its largest value, if $(x,y)$ is restricted to be on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

For the point $(x,y)$ and direction $(u_1,u_2)$, I found the directional derivative to be equal to $6xu_1+2yu_2$. Now how do we maximize this for the constraints $x^2+y^2=1$ and $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality: $|6x\cdot u_1 + 2y\cdot u_2| \leq \sqrt{(36x^2 +4y^2)(u_1^2 + u_2^2)} = \sqrt{32x^2 + 4} \leq \sqrt{36} = 6$. Thus the max value is $6$.

Answer (score 0):

As you know directional derivatives is eual to dot product of  $$\triangledown g*\vec u=|\triangledown g||\vec u|cos(\alpha)$$  where $\vec u$ is unit vector.

$$|\triangledown g|cos(\alpha)$$ and to maximize we should take $\alpha=0$. Now, we need to maximize $|\triangledown g|=\sqrt {36x^2+4y^2}=\sqrt {4+32x^2}$ then it reached maximum for $x=1$ (you can find it by derivatives of one variable) so answer is $6$.